# Multiple Actions for Single Button Based on Segue Source

Tags: ios, uiviewcontroller, segue, ibaction

I have ViewControllerA and ViewControllerB, both are table VCs that contain a list of items.  Right now, you can click "Add Items" on ViewControllerA that will open ListViewController where you can select/add new items from a list...there's a bar button 'Done' item that will take you back to ViewControllerA when you've made your selection.

So far I've done all this just by dragging my 'Done' button to Exit in Storyboards and selected the unwind action I've created (hence no example code to show).

Now I want to be on ViewControllerB, click an 'Edit' button which takes me to the same ListViewController where I can make edits and unwind back to ViewControllerB.  In Storyboard when I drag the 'Done' button and select the ViewControllerB unwind action it removes the action from ViewControllerA.

**My question:** do I have to scratch the Storyboard drag/drop and do this all programmatically?  Is it even possible to have a single button perform multiple actions based on the source ViewController?

I had a difficult time coming up with an accurate search query so this was tough to troubleshoot.

Answer (score 0):

This can be done with enum like first define different state or action

```
typedef enum {
    firstAction,
    secondAction,
    soOnnn.....
} ActionTypeType;
```

now when you are going to push your controller define a property like

```
@property (nonatomic, assign) LeagueType actionType;
```

and set this to your desired action

```
[backButton addTarget:self action:@selector(commonAction:) forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchUpInside];
```

and set a switch case for different action like

```
-(void)commonAction:(id)sender {

 switch(_actiontype) {

 case firstAction: { // do you code here }
 }
}
```